# Reading internal storage file is taking too much time in Android

Tags: java, android, json

I have a large JSON data around 20 MB (I create this data using `JSON.stringify` 
 from JavaScript code). I 'm writing this JSON data to an internal storage file on Android Device and reading it later. So When I read the file it's taking too much time, I don't know whether its reading or not. One more thing I need to Read in the Main thread only.

The below code works fine if I pass data value "Hello World" in `WriteFile` method, But it fails with the large JSON

```
public String ReadFile()
{
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    String FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(FILE_NAME)));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line + "\n");
            alert("Reading File: " + ++count);
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        alert(e.toString());
    }

    return text.toString();
}

public String WriteFile(String data)
{
    String FILE_NAME = "file.txt";
    String result = "";
  try {
      FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
      result = "Success";
      fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        result="Error";
   }

    return result;
}
```

I have added one alert in while `loop` also, but I cannot see any alert message. I have not seen even the `Exception` message also.

so there can be two problems.

1. There is something wrong in writing to file (But I don't know how to verify this? because I don't think there is any way to view internal storage file).
2. Something wrong in my reading code.

**Update1:**

If let's say I cannot read so large file in Java native code, then Is there any way to read an internal storage Android file from WebView JavaScript code?

============================================================================

**Application Requirement**

I have an Android application, In which I have a WebView. I have copied the full javascript code (js and HTML files) to assets folder of the app. I'm writing to file from java native code and reading from java native code. I am getting all data from the server on app launch. My client has a very slow internet connection and its disconnected many times. So they want this app to be run in offline mode. Means app will get all the data at launch and We will store it somewhere and then read it throughout the app. If a user launches the app again it will get the old existing data. Actually, this data is very big so I'm storing it to the internal storage file.

Comment: "One more thing I need to Read in the Main thread only" -- no, you do not. Beyond that, I would expect your code to crash frequently with an `OutOfMemoryError`. You do not have heap space for lots of large buffers, and this code involves lots of large buffers: the 20MB string that you want to write, the copy of that string as a `byte[]`, and the incrementally-increasing buffers for each line. That assumes that you fix the bug in `WriteFile()` where you are writing an empty `StringBuffer` instead of the actual text (`data` is unused).

Comment: "because I don't think there is any way to view internal storage file" -- use an emulator and the Device File Explorer in Android Studio. Also note that `StringBuffer` performs worse than does `StringBuilder`, as is noted in [the `StringBuffer` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer).

Comment: @CommonsWare, sorry it was typo. I corrected code its `data` not `text`

Comment: @CommonsWare Can't I see file on Android device?

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can I fix the ReadFile method now?

Comment: "Can't I see file on Android device?" -- you might be able to for a `debug` build. To be honest, I forget off the top of my head. "so how can I fix the ReadFile method now?" -- your fundamental problem is "I have a large JSON data around 20 MB". If you wish to stick with that, then your disk I/O needs to be done inside of the `WebView` by JavaScript code (as I assume that is where the JavaScript is coming from). Or, find some other data storage pattern that does not involve huge contiguous buffers.

Comment: As per my knowledge We cannot do IO from WebView, because It wont be having privillege of writing/reading to/from Android internal storage.

Comment: I did not downvote the question. My understanding is that `WebView` has access to normal Web local storage options. Or, use [HTML message channels](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/23/replacing-addjavascriptinterface-html-message-channels.html) to communicate back to your main Android at finer granularity than 20MB.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I agree, but again size is the issue for web local storage

Comment: @CommonsWare I have observed that WriteFile finishes in seconds, But ReadFile is never returning.

Comment: Just a hunch, what would happen if you comment out the calls to `alert()`?

Comment: I do not come to know that what has happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the only way to be really sure why your code is taking a long time is to profile it.  We can't do that for you.

But here are some performance tips relevant to your code:

1. Don't read the entire 20MB JSON file into the Java heap / RAM memory unless you really need to do it.  (I am finding it difficult to understand why you are doing this.  For example, a typical JSON parser will happily<sup>1</sup> read input directly from a file.  Or if you are reading this so that you can send this to a client on the other end of an HTTP connection, you should be able to stream the data.)
2. Reading a file a line at a time and then stitching the lines back together is unnecessary.  It generates unnecessary garbage.  Extra garbage means more work for the GC, which slows you down. If the lines are long, you have the added performance "hit" of using a internal `StringBuilder` to build each line.

   Reading to a recycled `char[]`, then appending the `char[]` content to the `StringBuilder` will be faster than appending lines.
3. Your `StringBuilder` will repeatedly "grow" its backing character array to accommodate the characters as you append them.  This generates garbage and leads to unnecessary copying.  (Implementations typically "grow" the array exponentially to avoid `O(N^2)` behavior.  However the expansions still affect performance, and can result in up to 3 times the peak memory usage than is actually required.)

   One way to avoid this is to get an initial estimate of the number of characters you are going to add and set the `StringBuilder` "capacity" accordingly.  You may be able to estimate the number of characters from the file size.  (It depends on the encoding.)
4. Look for a way to do it using existing standard Java libraries; e.g. `Files.copy` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, or `Files.readAllBytes`
5. Look for an existing 3rd-party library method; e.g. Apache Commons IO has an `IOUtils.toString(Reader)` method.  The chances are that *they* will have spent a lot of time figuring out how to do this *efficiently*.  Reusing a well engineered, well maintained library is likely to saves you time.
6. Don't put a trace print (I assume that is what `alert` is ...) in the middle of a loop that could be called millions of times.  (Duh!)

---

<sup>1 - Parser are cheerful once you get to know them :-)</sup>